# Inquiring pod and service subnets from inside Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kube-apiserver

How can one inquire the Kubernetes pod and service subnets in use (e.g. `10.244.0.0/16` and `10.96.0.0/12` respectively) from inside a Kubernetes cluster in a portable and simple way?

For instance, `kubectl get cm -n kube-system kubeadm-config -o yaml` reports `podSubnet` and `serviceSubnet`. But this is not fully portable because a cluster may have been set up by another means than `kubeadm`.

`kubectl get cm -n kube-system kube-proxy -o yaml` reports `clusterCIDR` (i.e. pod subnet) and `kubectl get pod -n kube-system kube-apiserver-master1 -o yaml` reports the value
passed as command-line option `--service-cluster-ip-range` to `kube-apiserver` (i.e. service subnet). `master1` stands for the name of any control plane node. But this seems a bit complex.

Is there a better way available e.g. with the Kubernetes 1.17 API?

Comment: Could you specify what format you would like to get?
Its all pods and svc from cluster, subnets, namespaces? List only of pods or only of services?

Comment: @PjoterS I'd expect two strings in CIDR notation that identify the two subnets, i.e. both pods and services across the entire cluster (all namepaces). The question already says so.

Comment: From your [deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62277344/kubernetes-cluster-nodes-have-been-assigned-wrong-podcidrs-how-to-repair): "Or are you saying that there has been no arrangement between SO and k8s and that they are just sending folks like me astray from their GitHub site?". It is hard to say for a specific open-source project, but mostly, the Stack Overflow community finds exactly what you are saying - the corporate backer of a project does not have the resources to support its product, so sends people to a volunteer site instead.

Comment: There are some Meta discussions on this [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253394) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253849) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327707). The bottom line is that it is not necessarily wrong for a company to send people here, but (a) not everyone who comes here is on the right site, and (b) third parties don't get to decide what it is on-topic here. Even the mighty Google `:=)`.

Comment: There were a couple of close-vote recommendations to move the question to [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) prior to the question being deleted. I wonder whether that would be a better location for it.

Comment: @halfer Thanks for the specific links. This was constructive input as far a I am concerned. Perhaps I'll ask around and raise the issue also at KubeCon.

Comment: No worries. Of course, you can ask a Meta question about it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it would be possible to obtain what you want in a portable and simple way.
If you don't specify Cidr's parameters it will assign default one.

As you have many ways to run kubernetes as unmanaged clusters like kubeadm, minikbue, k3s, micork8s or managed like Cloud providers (GKE, Azure, AWS) it's hard to find one way to list all cidrs in all environments. Another obstacle can be versions of Kubernetes or CNI.

In Kubernetes 1.17 [Release notes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.17.md#deprecations-and-removals) you can find information that

> Deprecate the default service IP CIDR. The previous default was `10.0.0.0/24` which will be removed in 6 months/2 releases. Cluster admins must specify their own desired value, by using `--service-cluster-ip-range` on kube-apiserver.

As example of Kubeadm: `$ kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr 10.100.0.0/12 --service-cidr 10.99.0.0/12`

There are a few ways to get this pod and service-cidr:

```
$ kubectl cluster-info dump | grep -E '(service-cluster-ip-range|cluster-cidr)'
                            "--service-cluster-ip-range=10.99.0.0/12",
                            "--cluster-cidr=10.100.0.0/12",



$ kubeadm config view | grep Subnet
  podSubnet: 10.100.0.0/12
  serviceSubnet: 10.99.0.0/12
```

But if you will check all pods in this cluster, some pods are starting with 192.168.190.X or 192.168.137.X

```
$ kubectl get pods -A -owide
NAMESPACE     NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE    IP                NODE             NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
default       nginx                                      1/1     Running   0          62m    192.168.190.129   kubeadm-worker   <none>           <none>
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-77c5fc8d7f-9n6m5   1/1     Running   0          118m   192.168.137.66    kubeadm-master   <none>           <none>
kube-system   calico-node-2kx2v                          1/1     Running   0          117m   10.128.0.4        kubeadm-worker   <none>           <none>
kube-system   calico-node-8xqd9                          1/1     Running   0          118m   10.128.0.3        kubeadm-master   <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-66bff467f8-sgmkw                   1/1     Running   0          120m   192.168.137.65    kubeadm-master   <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-66bff467f8-t84ht                   1/1     Running   0          120m   192.168.137.67    kubeadm-master   <none>           <none>
```

If you will describe any `CNI` pods you can find another CIDRs:

```
CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR:               192.168.0.0/16
```

For GKE example you will have:
node CIDRs

```
$ kubectl describe node | grep CIDRs
PodCIDRs:                     10.52.1.0/24
PodCIDRs:                     10.52.0.0/24
PodCIDRs:                     10.52.2.0/24

$ gcloud container clusters describe cluster-2 --zone=europe-west2-b | grep Cidr
clusterIpv4Cidr: 10.52.0.0/14
  clusterIpv4Cidr: 10.52.0.0/14
  clusterIpv4CidrBlock: 10.52.0.0/14
  servicesIpv4Cidr: 10.116.0.0/20
  servicesIpv4CidrBlock: 10.116.0.0/20
  podIpv4CidrSize: 24
servicesIpv4Cidr: 10.116.0.0/20
```

Honestly I don't think there is an easy and portable way to list all podCidrs and serviceCidrs in one simple command.